# My VueJS 2 script won't set a boolean and a number correctly, rendering the whole app not reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, fetch-api

I have a Vue 2 template that, on mount, calls an endpoint, and then sets the component data to the data fetched from that endpoint.

I've got an issue though, but only on that page: there are no Vue components in the Vue Dev Tools, and when I change the data in the .then() statement after the call, the data won't actually change ( I guess that makes it not reactive, right ? ).

```
<template>
  <div class="resume-creation">
      <p>{{ step }}</p>
      <p>{{ loading }}</p>
      <div
        v-cloak
        v-if="(step === 1 || step === 2) && !loading"
        :class="{
          'resume-private-informations-container-form': !activitySectorListOpened,
          'resume-activity-sector-container-form': activitySectorListOpened,
        }"
      >
        "TEST 1 OR 2"
        <v-resume-creation-step1 :......>
        </v-resume-creation-step1>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

export default {
  ...
  data: function () {
    return {
      step: 1,
      loading: true,
      ...
  },
  mounted: function () {
    this.axios
      .get(Routing.generate("app_api_get_resumes"))
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data !== undefined) {
          this.$set(this, "loading", false);
          this.$set(this, "step", response.data.currentStep);
          let resume = response.data.entity;
          // I've tried the standard: 
          this.loading = false;
          this.step = response.data.currentStep;

          ...some more data setting from the response
        }
      });
},
```

I know it fetches data, I know it goes through that response.data undefined check, so it's probably a deeper issue.

If I set the "loading" state to flse outside of this fetch() part it does seem to work okay.

I just started working on that project, hence why it's using VueJS 2 and so far I haven't had any major issue like that one. This also happens further down the nested components with the exact same fetch + data setting setup.

Any ideas of what could the issue be ? I've been at it since yesterday, and have tried anything, most issues I found online were mostly people trying to set objects improperly, but there it's not even an object, it's only a boolean and a number, which should work with the `this.propertyName = value`.

I tried using this `this.propertyName = value` at first, which didn't work, so I tried using `Vue.set(...)`, also didn't work, it said "Vue is not defined", so I tried `this.$set(...)`, which resulted in the same issue as `this.propertyName = value`.

I tried changing from a `fetch().then()` statement to an async/await, but from what I've read it's not really possible here.

I just expected it to be straightforward and for the `{{ step }}` and `{{ loading }}` to reflect the actual state of the variable.

Comment: It's really straightforward, in fact. You don't need $set because the values already exist in data, which is the requirement for easy reactivity in V2. "I guess that makes it not reactive, right ? " - much more likely this makes it not actually changed. The reason is that the values aren't what you expect, or there's a problem with the request, or the code in mounted() in general. "I tried changing from a fetch()" - you don't use fetch, you use axios. This could be the problem, or anything else. The question requires https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , currently there's no way to reproduce.

Comment: I just tried using an actual fetch() as well, which didn't work either. I console logged the data and it does seem to be full. Thanks for the link I'll try to see what I can do

Comment: The question needs debugging details. console.log isn't a good way to debug but this at least could make it more clear

Comment: What debugging details could be useful there ? I've never managed to properly debug this project, it really needs a overhaul

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint right inside then() and list what response.data is?

Comment: Yes, here's the structure:
{
    "entity": {
        "sortedGeolocations": [],
        "candidate": {
            "email": "myemail"
        },
        "contracts": [],
        "remuneration": {
            "timeContext": "monthly",
            "net": false
        },
        "experiences": [],
        "formations": [],
        "workingTimes": [],
        "documents": [],
        "uuid": "properUuid",
        "currentStep": 0,
        "opportunityStatus": "active",
        "progression": 0,
        "languages": [],
        "permits": []
    },
    ...moreData
}

Comment: Apparently it does change the data ( I logged this.step and this.loading, and they do have the proper value ), but it doesn't rerender the template

Comment: Then `this.step = response.data.currentStep` is supposed to work, there's no place for error. If there's something that prevents the comp from working normally and rerender, it's supposed to be visible in console. If the problem persists, please, provide a way to reproduce it. It's supposed to be reproducible with mocked data at this point.